# Is there a way to enable the 'prompt()' code without some sort of button?

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a rock, paper, scissors game and I have added lizard and Spock parts for extra. However, it is quite plain. I have added buttons which rival the computer using Math.random but what I want to do is make it so I can make it automatically prompt you without a button of some sort. I want to do this so I can add a secret code word that allows you to win every match. Here is my current code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Rock, Paper, Scissors!</title>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<button onclick="play(0);">Rock</button>
<button onclick="play(1);">Paper</button>
<button onclick="play(2);">Scissors</button>
<button onclick="play(3);">Lizard</button>
<button onclick="play(4);">Spock</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the Javascript code.

```
var gestures = ["rock", "paper", "scissors", "lizard", "spock"];

var rules = {
    rock:     { scissors: "breaks",  lizard: "crushes"     },
    paper:    { rock:     "covers",  spock:  "disproves"   },
    scissors: { paper:    "cuts",    lizard: "decapitates" },
    lizard:   { paper:    "eats",    spock:  "poisons"     },
    spock:    { scissors: "smashes", rock:   "vaporizes"   }
};

function play(index) {
    var your = gestures[index];
    var mine = gestures[Math.floor(5 * Math.random())];
    if (your === mine) return alert("Draw. We both played " + your + ".");
    var win = rules[your].hasOwnProperty(mine);
    var result = win ? "win" : "lose";
    var a = win ? your : mine;
    var b = win ? mine : your;
    alert("You " + result + ": " + a + " " + rules[a][b] + " " + b + ".");
}
```

You can see the website of the game at https://8bitguys.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/

PS. I am a newbie to Javascript

Comment: When do you need the `prompt()` ?

Comment: I need the prompt when I come onto the website. I was hoping it would just pop up. Is that possible in anyway?

Comment: Why not use a onkeypress event on the body tag of the html page? So you will check for a certain key to be pressed (eg. "p" for prompt and will be ascii code 112 of the keypress event). Once it is pressed throw the popup, this way it is "hidden" to the user but still there. Find ascii codes here:
http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-p-uppercase-ascii-code-80.html

Comment: in case you just start it on page load:
just do `play(prompt("do you want to win?"));` right after the `play()` function

Comment: @SchalkKeun Thank you! I needed the play feature. Please make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a `onkeypress` event on the body tag of the html page? So you will check for a certain key to be pressed (eg. "p" for prompt and will be ascii code *112* of the keypress event). Once it is pressed throw the popup, this way it is "hidden" to the user but still there. Find ascii codes here: http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-p-uppercase-ascii-code-80.html

OR

In case you just start it on page load: just do `play(prompt("do you want to win?"));` right after the `play()` function